# Distribute Definitions to different Evaluator

Tags: parallelization, kernel, cells, kernel-startup

I would like to pass on a definition from one Kernel to the other. With that I mean manually configured Kernels. In this case, I do not want to use the inbuilt Parallelization options, in order to enable parallel computation in the background while still using the main Kernel for other tasks. So would you know a way to share the definition in the following example?
This code is in the first cell with the main Kernel:

```
Clear[f]; f[x_] := x^x; f[2]
DistributeDefinitions[f];
SetSharedFunction[f];
```

In another Cell, this code should use the definition of f:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], Evaluator -> "Secundo"];
f[2]
```

However, it outputs f[2] unevaluated even though I tried to share the definition. How can I do this without redefining the function on the new Kernel explicitly (functions of interest are quite longish) and without writing them into a package to load each time?

The final purpose is to distribute parallel tasks from a second Kernel while the first one still executes my calculations on the main Kernel using the remaining cores:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], Evaluator -> "Secundo"];
CloseKernels[];LaunchKernels[6];
DistributeDefinitions[f,g,h];
eids = Table[ParallelSubmit[{k}, {k,f[g[h[k]]]}], {k,10^6}];
res =.; resList ={};PrintTemporary[Dynamic[res]];
AbsoluteTiming[Table[{res, id, eids} = WaitNext[eids]; 
AppendTo[resList,res];, {i,Length[eids]}]];
resList
```

In case you were wondering... But for this I simply need the second Kernel to get the information (about f,g,h) from the first one as in the minimal example above.